# Java multilevel menu structure

Tags: java, tree, navigation

I'm building a web application in Java (Tapestry 5).
I want to create a multilevel menu where I can show the root elements for example at the top of my page and the children of the selected on the left.

To implement this I was thinking to use a tree structure like this:

```
public class SiteMap {

private List<MenuItem> root;

public class MenuItem {

    private String pageFileName;
    private String pageNavigationName;

    private List<MenuItem> children;
    private MenuItem parent;

    public MenuItem(String pageFileName, String pageNavigationName, MenuItem parent) {
        this.pageFileName = pageFileName;
        this.pageNavigationName = pageNavigationName;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getPageFileName() {
        return pageFileName;
    }

    public String getPageNavigationName() {
        return pageNavigationName;
    }

    public List<MenuItem> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public MenuItem getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }
}
}
```

Now what if I want to build a menu based on the children of 1 parent item (only have the pageFileName - String) somewhere in the tree. Ill have to traverse recursively through the tree to find this parent item based on the pageFileName (String) , which seems not a good way.

Is this (using a tree structure) the right way to implement this? Or is there a better option?
Any thoughts and hints are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MenuItem root = null;
MenuItem curr = myMenuItem;
while(curr.getParent() != null) {
    curr = curr.getParent(); 
}
root = curr;
```

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way, that code will run very fast, especailly since you aren't going to have millions of menu entries.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
The problem here is, that I don't have "curr" as MenuItem datatype, but just as a String (name of the page file). So I'd have to recursively(?) search the tree for the right parent with this pageFileName.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood, maybe just add a HashMap<String, MenuItem> for fast lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use MenuItem for both parent and children and keep a reference from each child to its parent?

```
List<MenuItem> children; // empty/null for leaf nodes
MenuItem parent; // null for root nodes
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry it was supposed to be that way (my fault).
But when building the menu in my webapplication, I'll have to find the children based on the parents pageFileName (String). So I'll have to loop through the tree to find this parent item I guess?

Comment: I updated my code as how I meant it to be, sorry for the confusion. (was mixed up with older code)